# How to know the number of Spark jobs and stages in (broadcast) join query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.1.2.

I am trying to understand various spark UI tab displays vis-a-vis as a job runs. I use `spark-shell --master local` and doing the following `join` query:

```
val df = Seq(
  (55, "Canada", -1, "", 0),
  (77, "Ontario", 55, "/55", 1),
  (100, "Toronto", 77, "/55/77", 2),
  (104, "Brampton", 100, "/55/77/100", 3)
).toDF("id", "name", "parentId", "path", "depth")

val dfWithPar = df.as("df1").
  join(df.as("df2"), $"df1.parentId" === $"df2.Id", "leftouter").
  select($"df1.*", $"df2.name" as "parentName")

dfWithPar.show
```

This is the physical query plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [Id#11, name#12, parentId#13, path#14, depth#15, name#25 AS parentName#63]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [parentId#13], [Id#24], LeftOuter, BuildRight
   :- LocalTableScan [Id#11, name#12, parentId#13, path#14, depth#15]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- LocalTableScan [Id#24, name#25]
```

I've got two questions about the query execution.

1. Why are there two jobs for the query?

   [image: Spark job view]
2. Why are the stage view shown for both jobs identical? Below is a screenshot of the stage view of job id 1 which is exactly the same of job id 0. Why?

   [image: Stage view of Stage 1 which is exactly same as Stage 0]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use **Spark 2.3.0** to answer your question (**2.3.1-SNAPSHOT** actually) since it is the latest and greatest at the time of this writing. That changes very little about query execution (if anything important) as the physical query plans in your 2.1.2 and my 2.3.0 are exactly the same (except the [per-query codegen stage ID](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23032) in round brackets).

---

After `dfWithPar.show` the structured query (that you built using Spark SQL's Dataset API for Scala) is optimized to the following physical query plan (I'm including it in my answer for better comprehension).

```
scala> dfWithPar.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [Id#11, name#12, parentId#13, path#14, depth#15, name#24 AS parentName#58]
+- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [parentId#13], [Id#23], LeftOuter, BuildRight
   :- LocalTableScan [Id#11, name#12, parentId#13, path#14, depth#15]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
      +- LocalTableScan [Id#23, name#24]
```

### Number of Spark Jobs

> Why are there two jobs for the query?

I'd say there are even three Spark jobs.

[image: Spark jobs of the broadcast join query in web UI]

**tl;dr** One Spark job is for `BroadcastHashJoinExec` physical operator whereas the other two are for `Dataset.show`.

In order to understand the query execution and the number of Spark jobs of a structured query, it is important to understand the difference between structured queries (described using Dataset API) and RDD API.

Spark SQL's Datasets and Spark Core's RDDs both describe distributed computations in Spark. RDDs are the Spark "assembler" language (akin to the JVM bytecode) while Datasets are higher-level descriptions of structured queries using SQL-like language (akin to JVM languages like Scala or Java as compared to the JVM bytecode I used earlier).

What's important is that structured queries using Dataset API eventually end up as a RDD-based distributed computation (which could be compared to how the Java or Scala compilers transform the higher-level languages to the JVM bytecode).

Dataset API is an abstraction over RDD API and when you call an action on a DataFrame or Dataset that action transforms them to RDDs.

With that, you should not be surprised that [Dataset.show](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L691) will in the end call  RDD action that in turn will run zero, one or many Spark jobs.

`Dataset.show` (with `numRows` equals 20 by default) in the end calls [showString](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L241) that [take(numRows + 1)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L254) to get an `Array[Row]`.

```
val takeResult = newDf.select(castCols: _*).take(numRows + 1)
```

In other words, `dfWithPar.show()` is equivalent of `dfWithPar.take(21)` which in turn is equivalent to `dfWithPar.head(21)` as far as the number of Spark jobs are concerned.

You can see them and their number of jobs in the SQL tab. They should all be equal.

[image: SQL tab in web UI]

`show` or `take` or `head` all lead to [collectFromPlan](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L3268) that triggers the Spark jobs (by calling [executeCollect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L3272)).

You should be certain that to answer your question about the number of jobs is to know how all the physical operators in the query work. You simply have to know their behaviour at runtime and whether they trigger Spark jobs at all.

[image]

#### BroadcastHashJoin and BroadcastExchangeExec Physical Operators

`BroadcastHashJoinExec` binary physical operator is used when the right side of a join can be broadcast (which is exactly `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` that is `10M` by default).

`BroadcastExchangeExec` unary physical operator is used to broadcast rows (of a relation) to worker nodes (to support `BroadcastHashJoinExec`).

When `BroadcastHashJoinExec` is executed (to generate a `RDD[InternalRow]`), it [creates a broadcast variable](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L67) that in turn executes `BroadcastExchangeExec` (on a [separate thread](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L76)).

That's why the **run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149** Spark job 0 was run.

You could see the single Spark job 0 ran if you executed the following:

```
// Just a single Spark job for the broadcast variable
val r = dfWithPar.rdd
```

That requires that the structured query is executed to produce a RDD that is then the target of the action to give the final result.

[image]

You would not have had the Spark job if you had not ended up with a broadcast join query.

#### RDD.take Operator

What I missed the very first moment when I answered the question was that the Dataset operators, i.e. `show`, `take` and `head`, will in the end lead to `RDD.take`.

> **take(num: Int): Array[T]** Take the first num elements of the RDD. It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit.

Please note when `take` says *"It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit."* That's the key to understand the number of Spark jobs in your broadcast join query.

Every iteration (in the description above) is a [separate Spark job starting with the very first partition and 4 times as many every following iteration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L1358):

```
// RDD.take
def take(num: Int): Array[T] = withScope {
  ...
  while (buf.size < num && partsScanned < totalParts) {
    ...
    val res = sc.runJob(this, (it: Iterator[T]) => it.take(left).toArray, p)
    ...
  }
}
```

Have a look at the following `RDD.take` with 21 rows.

```
// The other two Spark jobs
r.take(21)
```

You will get 2 Spark jobs as in your query.

[image]

Guess how many Spark jobs you will have if you executed `dfWithPar.show(1)`.

### Why Are Stages Identical?

> Why are the stage view shown for both jobs identical? Below is a screenshot of the stage view of job id 1 which is exactly the same of job id 0. Why?

That's easy to answer since both Spark jobs are from `RDD.take(20)`.

The first Spark job is to scan the first partition and since it had not enough rows led to another Spark job to scan more partitions.

Comment: Thanks. Got to know a lot. I still have few observations that probably don't match with latest Spark. e.g. 1) `val r = dfWithPar.rdd` doesn't trigger any job as u mention. 2) Spark 2.1.2 UI probably doesn't trigger a `ThreadPoolExecutor.run`. I don't see it on UI. ..But, I could gather that jobs are triggered in phases, as in first it triggers for 1 partition and then, as per requirement triggers for collecting remaining. That is probably why I see `Job 0` having 1 task always in its stage while `Job 1` has 4 tasks in its stage.

Comment: OK. Might be that there are indeed some changes in how query execution happens in 2.1.2 and 2.3.0. The end result is that you have 2 Spark jobs and that's how `Dataset.show` (and `RDD.take`) collect the required number of rows.