# Why does this simple spark application create so many jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand how jobs, stages, partitions and tasks interact in Spark. So I wrote the following simple script:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
case class DataRow(customer: String, ppg_desc: String, yyyymm: String, qty: Integer)
val data = Seq(
     DataRow("23","300","201901",45),
     DataRow("19","234","201902", 0),
     DataRow("23","300","201901", 22),
     DataRow("19","171","201901", 330)
     )
val df = data.toDF()
val sums = df.groupBy("customer","ppg_desc","yyyymm").sum("qty")
sums.show()
```

Since I have only one action (the `sums.show` call), I expected to see one job. Since there is a groupBy involved, I expected this job to have 2 stages. Also, since I have not changed any defaults, I expected to have 200 partitions after the group by and therefore 200 tasks. However, when I ran this in spark-shell, I see 5 jobs being created:

[image]

All of these jobs appear to be triggered by the `sums.show()` call. I am running via spark-shell and lscpu for my docker container shows:

[image]

Looking within Job 0, I see the two stages I expect:

[image]

But looking in Job 3, I see that the first stage is skipped and the second executed. This, I gather, is because the input is already cached.

[image]

What I'm failing to understand is, how does Spark decide how many jobs to schedule? Is it related to the number of partitions to be processed?

Comment: How do you submit your job ? Can you show your `spark-submit` configuration ?

Comment: I'm just executing this within spark-shell. When I execute the show() line the stages all run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385724/how-to-know-the-number-of-spark-jobs-and-stages-in-broadcast-join-query